# Run kafka server with additional 3rd party plugins for stats collection, logging etc

Tags: java, plugins, apache-kafka, jvm

Coming from ActiveMQ background. ActiveMQ uses a spring xml configuration file to run the broker and we can inject any 3rd party plugins like a custom stats collector, a custom logging plugin using beans in the spring config file.

For Kafka I want to re-use the same stats collector plugin and launch it alongside Kafka to collect additional system stats like threads, cpu etc.

I haven't been able to find a way after perusing through the Kafka documentation. Does anyone has a viable solution for this? Is this even achievable without modifying the Kafka source?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to collect CPU and other metrics related to Kafka?

Comment: Yes I want to do that. There is already a module that we have created and use in other processes. I wanted to see if Kafka can be easily configured with a plugin or if there are other alternatives.

Comment: Kafka expose it's metric throw JMX. You can google for how to programmatically read JMX. It is commonly used in Java applications. I wrote an article in https://medium.com/@mousavi310/monitor-apache-kafka-using-grafana-and-prometheus-873c7a0005e2 that might give you an idea. You can also check it's reference for more information.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi Thanks for the link. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found about metrics.reporter configuration in kafka. We can provide and implementation of MetricsReporter interface. Within the init method of this interface, I initialized and started my 3rd party plugins for stats collection.

In server properties file, I added below property to enable the custom implementation of metrics reporter:

```
metric.reporters=abc.kafka.plugin.KafkaMetricPlugin
```

Many other monitoring solutions like linkedin's cruise-control, confluent's control center use this method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no source code to modify. You can use any JMX metrics collector or Java Agent.

The Prometheus Java Agent is popular if you want a DIY approach, or there are vendor products such DataDog which ship Java agents.

For any tool you use, you can inject runtime args via `KAFKA_OPTS`

For Prometheus JMX exporter,

```
export KAFKA_OPTS='-javaagent:/path/to/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.9.jar=7071:/path/to/kafka-patterns.yml'
kafka-server-start /path/to/server.properties
```

Logging is handled by SLF4J, so you can configure that to your needs, with the default logger being log4j